How to block ambient light in a given volume (eevee)
I am new to Blender, coming up to speed on many concepts.
I am creating one of these 3D open floorplans. I have a world background image, which emits light in my scene.
Now I have a room which is supposed to be dark (except for a dim light inside), but which has no roof so we can see inside. I cannot figure out how to block the ambient light!
I have tried creating different planes or cubes to enclose this volume, using mixer with "is camera ray" to control the surface's opacity, but nothing works.
This is an example of a shader I have created, for a plane which is supposed to block light, but be transparent to the camera.

Setting then blend mode to alpha blend, and shadow mode to opaque for that material.
How should I go about that? Thanks!

I feel like light probes might do that? I don’t know.

I have tried that way, could not make it work

As far as I know, there is no way to do that. In EEVEE, ambient light is applied to every object without any kind of raytracing or other system to tell if it should be there or not.

Wow you're right, I completely enclosed the room, and the ambiant light was still there. That's a major bummer! I guess I will have to remove that light and rely on individual lights instead.
